# How to change styleTable on PHPWord?

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I have a problem with using the plugin phpword. I'm trying to change the style, but I can change the background of the cell and other parameters are considered by it.

```
$styleTable = array('borderColor'=>'006699',
                    'borderSize'=>6,
                    'cellMargin'=>50,
                    'valign'=>'center'
                   );
$styleFirstRow = array('bgColor'=>'6086B8',
                       'color'=>'white',
                       'bold'=>true,
                       'size'=>11,
                       'valign'=>'center'
                    );
$PHPWord->addTableStyle('myTable', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);
```

If you want to look my code, he as here : http://pastebin.com/pw36n3aW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem was, it came from my settings that do not exist.
Thank you for your time and help.

```
$styleFirstRow = array('bgColor'=>'#6086B8');
    $PHPWord->addTableStyle('myTable', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);

    $styleCellFirstRow = array('valign'=>'center'); 
    $styleCell = array('valign'=>'center'); 

$styleTextFirstRow = array('name'=>'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'color'=>'white','size'=>12);
    $styleParagprapheFirstRow = array('align'=>'center');
    $table->addCell(2200, $styleCellFirstRow)->addText('Type du rapporteur', $styleTextFirstRow, $styleParagprapheFirstRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this

```
array('borderColor'=>array('rgb' => '006699'), .....
```

Do you have this line in your code

```
$table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle');
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not focus, change the size or color of my items.

Comment: Yes I have : http://pastebin.com/pw36n3aW
If u want to look my code in integrality. you have now

Answer (score -3):

I think you need `#` to define color code

```
    $styleTable = array('borderColor'=>'#006699',....and so on
```

Comment: Thank you for this error, but it did not come from there.
I have the background color that appears as before.